# Combining Create and Index Views in one View in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, view, merge

I have a controller in my Dashboard Area and an action to return categories as a list to view and another action to create new category

My Actions:

```
         public ActionResult Categories() {
             return View(db.Categories.OrderBy(Categories => Categories.Name).ToList());
         }
         
         [HttpPost]
         public RedirectToRouteResult NewCategory(string name, string address, string parentId) {
             if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                 int? ParentID = null;
                 if (parentId != "null") {
                     ParentID = parentId.AsInt();
                 }
                 Category oCategory = new Category();
                 oCategory.Name = name;
                 oCategory.Address = address;
                 oCategory.ParentID = ParentID;
                 db.Categories.Add(oCategory);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 db.Dispose();
                 db = null;
             }
             return RedirectToAction("Categories");
         }
```

I have a pure HTML form inside the Categories View to get user inputs to create a new category and a block that represents the categories that I already have.

I have a Select and several Foreach loops that iterates through categories from parent to children inside my form.

Here is the code:

```
                    <select name="parentID" id="parentCategoryId">
                        <option value="null" selected>nothing</option>
                        @foreach (var Category in Model) {
                            if (Category.ParentID == null) {
                                <option value="@Category.ID">@Category.Name</option>
                                foreach (var SubCategory1 in Model) {
                                    if (SubCategory1.ParentID == Category.ID) {
                                        <option value="@SubCategory1.ID">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            »
                                            &nbsp;
                                            @SubCategory1.Name
                                        </option>
                                        foreach (var SubCategory2 in Model) {
                                            if (SubCategory2.ParentID == SubCategory1.ID) {
                                                <option value="@SubCategory2.ID">
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    »
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    @SubCategory2.Name
                                                </option>
                                                foreach (var SubCategory3 in Model) {
                                                    if (SubCategory3.ParentID == SubCategory2.ID) {
                                                        <option value="@SubCategory3.ID">
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            »
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                            @SubCategory3.Name
                                                        </option>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
```

Inside the view I get the data from Model using :

```
@model IEnumerable<project.Models.Category>
```

But I need another Model object to use here:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and validation operation!

The question is how can I combine these two views?

And now I’m stuck with this error:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create model:

```
public class CategoryModel {

      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Address {get;set;}
      pubic string ParentId {get;set;}

      public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}
```

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Categories() {
      var model = new CategoryModel();

      model.Categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(Categories => Categories.Name).ToList();

      return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult NewCategory(CategoryModel model) {
     if (ModelState.IsValid) {
             int? ParentID = null;

             if (model.ParentId != "null") {
                 ParentID = model.ParentId.AsInt();
             }

             Category oCategory = new Category();
             oCategory.Name = Model.Name;
             oCategory.Address = Model.Address;
             oCategory.ParentID = ParentID;
             db.Categories.Add(oCategory);
             db.SaveChanges();
             db.Dispose();
             db = null;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Categories");
 }
```

and in the view:

```
 @model project.Models.CategoryModel
```

now you can create fields like in the same view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model=>model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```